# sending value from localstorage to php via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, cart

im trying send value from localstorage to php using ajax, but im getting notice undefined index:data when i try to send without parament data im getting only empty array( Array()) in php

**php**

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST)) {
  $decoded = json_decode($_POST['data']);
  print_r($decoded);
  var_dump($decoded);}
?>
```

**ajax**

```
var jsonString = localStorage.getItem("totalCost");
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonString);
console.log(jsonString);
console.log(typeof jsonString);
$.ajax({
    url:"read.php",
    method: "POST",
    data:  {'data': jsonString },
    success: function(res){
        console.log(res);
}
```

*ps*
console.log(jsonString) and
console.log(res) works pefect

Comment: Open the browser's developer tools and look at the network tab to see what your AJAX call is sending to PHP.

Comment: you dont need `''` around data in your ajax call

Comment: But it doesn't hurt anything @Baracuda078

Comment: @JayBlanchard ok, didn't know that. I was learned to not use them

Comment: @JayBlanchard  yes in response tab it shows the value

Comment: If `$_POST['data']` is undefined that means that you did not send a value with your AJAX call.